# Escaping the literal in jQuery DateTime Picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using [DateTime Picker](http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) for datetime picker. Now i have faced a situation where i have to give the format like `01/05/2015 23 h 59`. I have tried ecsaping the `h`, but its not working.

I have tried the following options
`H \h ii` **23 \23 59**
 `H 'h' ii`  **23 '23' 59**
 `H [h] ii`  **23 [23] 59**

Anyone have any suggestion how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that h gets replace with the hour so I thought of a workaround. I chose a random string "qqq" you can make it anything you want, it just needs to not contain letters that get replaced with the hour, minute, month, etc, than when the value for your input changes you replace that string with "h"

```
$("#yourInput").change(function(){
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace("qqq", "h"))
});

$("#yourInput").datetimepicker({format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh qqq ii'});
```